# Calculate offset arrow tip vs arrow line FabricJS

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a function that allows you to live-draw an arrow on the canvas. What I have so far is working but I'm stuck on the calculation that sticks the arrow tip to the end of the line while moving. I've attached an image to show that the angle is calculated correctly.

[image]

I just need to move the tip but I can't figure it out. Help greatly appreciated!!

PS: The tip is a path, but maybe there's a better solution?

```
function drawArrowMouseDown( e ) {
    var mouse = canvas.getPointer(e.e);
    started = true;
    lastX = mouse.x;
    lastY = mouse.y;

    var $color = colors[self.selectedColor] != undefined ? colors[self.selectedColor] : 'red';

    var line = new fabric.Line( [lastX,lastY,lastX,lastY], {
        stroke: $color,
        strokeWidth:  3,
        lockScalingX: true,
        lockScalingY: true,
        lockRotation: true,
        hasBorders:   false,
        hasControls:  false,
        perPixelTargetFind: true,
        fill:         $color,
        strokeLineCap: 'round'
    });
    line.lockScalingX = line.lockScalingY = true;

    var tip = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L -20 15 M 0 0 L 20 15 z', {
        left: lastX,
        top: lastY,
        strokeWidth: 3,
        stroke: 'blue',
        strokeLineCap: 'round',
        hasControls: false,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
    });

    tip.line = line;
    line.tip = tip;

    canvas.add(line);
    canvas.add(tip);

    tip.bringToFront();

    canvas.setActiveObject(line);
    canvas.renderAll();
}
function drawArrowMouseMove( e ) {
    if(!started) {
        return false;
    }
    var mouse = canvas.getPointer(e.e);

    var line = canvas.getActiveObject();
    line.set('x2', mouse.x).set('y2', mouse.y);
    line.setCoords();

    var tip = line.get('tip');
    tip.set({ x1: mouse.x, y1: mouse.y, x2: lastX, y2: lastY });

    var x = tip.get('x2') - tip.get('x1');
    var y = tip.get('y2') - tip.get('y1');

    var angle;
    if (x == 0) {
        if (y == 0) {
            angle = 0;
        }
        else if (y > 0) {
            angle = Math.PI / 2;
        }
        else {
            angle = Math.PI * 3 / 2;
        }
    }
    else if (y == 0) {
        if (x > 0) {
            angle = 0;
        }
        else {
            angle = Math.PI;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (x < 0) {
            angle = Math.atan(y / x) + Math.PI;
        }
        else if ( y < 0) {
            angle = Math.atan(y / x) + (2 * Math.PI);
        }
        else {
            angle = Math.atan(y / x);
        }
    }
    angle = angle * 180 / Math.PI;

    tip.set('angle', angle-90);

    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angle calculation is just a bit off.

Instead use atan2 with the result normalized to PI*2:

```
var dx = tip.get('x2') - tip.get('x1');

var dy = tip.get('x2') - tip.get('x1');

var PI2=Math.PI*2;

var radianAngle = ( Math.atan2(dy,dx)+PI2 ) % PI2;
```

Comment: Thanks, although it wasn't the question it's always ok to make code more efficient. I'm not sure though how to implement it. The code for the angle calculation is not mine; I got it from another SO answer. What should this snippet replace?